# Jasmine replace class while testing another class

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I have a plain old class, not a component, with this method that I want to test

```js
static fromJson(json: any): ClientDTO {
    const ret: ClientDTO = Object.assign(new ClientDTO(), json)

    const dp = new DateWithoutTimePipe()

    ret.contractStart = dp.transform(json.contractStart)
    ret.contractEnd = dp.transform(json.contractEnd)

    return ret
}
```

As part of my test method, I want to verify that the transform method was called with the expected parameters.  I figured I need some type of spy, but because `DateWithoutTimePipe` isn't injected, I'm not sure how to fake out that class in my test.

I had originally tried the below, and of course immediately realized the spy is never actually used.

```js
it('should decode dates', () => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('DateWithoutTimePipe', ['transform'])
    const dates = {'contractStart': '2020-01-01', 'contractEnd': '2030-02-03'}
    const dto = ClientDTO.fromJson(dates)

    expect(dto).toBeInstanceOf(ClientDTO)
    expect(spy.transform).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)

    const all = spy.transform.calls.all()

    expect(all[0].args).toBe(['2020-01-01'])
    expect(all[1].args).toBe(['2030-02-03'])
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [spyOn(obj, methodName)](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOn) to install a spy onto an existing object.

E.g.

`MyClass.ts`:

```js
import { ClientDTO } from './ClientDTO';
import { DateWithoutTimePipe } from './DateWithoutTimePipe';

export class MyClass {
  static fromJson(json: any): ClientDTO {
    const ret: ClientDTO = Object.assign(new ClientDTO(), json);

    const dp = new DateWithoutTimePipe();

    ret.contractStart = dp.transform(json.contractStart);
    ret.contractEnd = dp.transform(json.contractEnd);

    return ret;
  }
}
```

`ClientDTO.ts`

```js
export class ClientDTO {
  public contractStart;
  public contractEnd;
}
```

`DateWithoutTimePipe.ts`:

```js
export class DateWithoutTimePipe {
  public transform(data) {}
}
```

`MyClass.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';
import { DateWithoutTimePipe } from './DateWithoutTimePipe';
import { ClientDTO } from './ClientDTO';

describe('62461783', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const transformSpy = spyOn(DateWithoutTimePipe.prototype, 'transform').and.callFake((data) => {
      if (data === '2020-01-01') {
        return 'transformed 2020-01-01';
      }
      if (data === '2030-02-03') {
        return 'transformed 2030-02-03';
      }
    });
    const json = { contractStart: '2020-01-01', contractEnd: '2030-02-03' };
    const actual = MyClass.fromJson(json);
    const all = transformSpy.calls.all();
    expect(all[0].args).toEqual(['2020-01-01']);
    expect(all[1].args).toEqual(['2030-02-03']);
    expect(actual).toBeInstanceOf(ClientDTO);
    expect(transformSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
Executing 1 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 45771)

Test Suites & Specs:
(node:41885) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

1. 62461783
   ✔ should pass (6ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   1 of 1
Expects: 4 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.028 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks, it never occurred to me to spy on the prototype.